# (MAC M1) ld: library not found for -lomp

Tags: c, macos, openmp, llvm, apple-m1

I have a problem with the use of libomp and llvm. I tried several solutions but without success.

Now I think I'm close to the goal, does anyone have an idea to solve the problem ?

This is what my shell returns when I try to compile a file using OpenMP :

```
theosouchon@MacBook-Pro-de-Theo Test % clang -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp fichier.c -v -lomp
Homebrew clang version 13.0.1
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
 "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1/bin/clang-13" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-macosx12.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Werror=undef-prefix -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name fichier.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=non-leaf -fno-rounding-math -munwind-tables -fcompatibility-qualified-id-block-type-checking -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu apple-m1 -target-feature +v8.5a -target-feature +fp-armv8 -target-feature +neon -target-feature +crc -target-feature +crypto -target-feature +dotprod -target-feature +fp16fml -target-feature +ras -target-feature +lse -target-feature +rdm -target-feature +rcpc -target-feature +zcm -target-feature +zcz -target-feature +fullfp16 -target-feature +sha2 -target-feature +aes -target-abi darwinpcs -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 711 -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/Users/theosouchon/Documents/ENSEEIHT/2SN/S2/OpenMP/Test -resource-dir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1/lib/clang/13.0.1 -fopenmp -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1/lib/clang/13.0.1/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/usr/include -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/theosouchon/Documents/ENSEEIHT/2SN/S2/OpenMP/Test -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fmax-type-align=16 -fcolor-diagnostics -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /var/folders/n8/6b9z9spn25zg1k93m1__1hyw0000gn/T/fichier-6be4ef.o -x c fichier.c
clang -cc1 version 13.0.1 based upon LLVM 13.0.1 default target arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1/lib/clang/13.0.1/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch arm64 -platform_version macos 12.0.0 12.0.0 -syslibroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk -o a.out /var/folders/n8/6b9z9spn25zg1k93m1__1hyw0000gn/T/fichier-6be4ef.o -lomp -lSystem /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1/lib/clang/13.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: library not found for -lomp
clang-13: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Ps: avoid answers like install homebrew version arm64 and look for the library you need, this is not enough to make OpenMP work properly.

Comment: There's -lomp, but no -L/path/to/lib... Are you sure you're getting the correct flags from your pkg-config directory, perhaps needing to set LDFLAGS or PKG_CONFIG_PATH?

Comment: Hello, it is possible that I have misconfigured the flags. What type of path should I initialize them with?